# Abreviaturas en nombres / Abbreviations in names

Tags: abreviaturas

Según lo que tengo entendido (o lo que leí en Wikipedia), el nombre completo del Presidente de México es «Enrique Peña Nieto, GCB, GCIH, RE». Entiendo que Enrique es su nombre, que Peña es su apellido paterno y que Nieto es su apellido materno, pero ¿qué quieren decir «GCB», «GCIH» y «RE»?

*According to what I understand (or what I read on Wikipedia), the full name of the President of Mexico is "Enrique Peña Nieto, GCB, GCIH, RE." I understand that Enrique is his first name, that Peña is his paternal surname and that Nieto is his maternal surname, but what do "GCB," "GCIH" and "RE" mean?*

¡Muchas gracias con antelación! / *Thank you very much in advance!*

Comment: If you based your question in [the article in the English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enrique_Pe%C3%B1a_Nieto), see that all these abbreviations have a link to their own explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esas abreviaturas indican honores que ha recibido la persona cuyo nombre acompañan. En este caso:

- GCB: [Gran Cruz de la Orden del Baño](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orden_del_Ba%C3%B1o)
- GCIH: [Gran Collar de la Orden del Infante don Enrique](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orden_del_Infante_Don_Enrique) (*Henrique* en portugués)
- RE: [Caballero de la Orden del Elefante](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orden_del_Elefante) (*Ridder af Elefantordenen* en danés)

Comment: Parece que es el Orden del Elefante --> https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orden_del_Elefante

Comment: Pues sí, significa *Ridder af Elefantordenen*. Muchas gracias, @fedorqui